# How to make a form_for form helper in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I am using this helper method to create a date field with a hidden field:

```
module FormatHelper

  def datepicker_field(object, date)
    object.text_field(:date_selector, :class => "datepicker") +
    object.hidden_field(date.to_sym, :id => "real_date")
  end

end
```

In my forms I am using it like this:

```
<%= datepicker_field(f, :date) %>
```

It would be more elegant (and more similar to my other form elements) if I could simply do:

```
<%= f.datepicker_field(:date) %>
```

(`f` being the `form_for` block)

How can this be done in Rails?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you try looking at the source for other `form_for` elements? You can model it after those.

Answer (score 2):

Years ago I did something like this in an Rails 3.1 application:

```
# in config/initializers/form_helpers.rb
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper
      def datepicker(object_name, method)
        text_field(:date_selector, :class => "datepicker") + hidden_field(object_name, method, :id => "real_date")
      end
    end

    class FormBuilder
      def datepicker(date)
        @template.datepicker(@object_name, method)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can is create a subclass of `FormBuilder` and pass it to the `form_for`

```
= form_for @user, builder: StandardFormBuilder do |f|
```

And then create a file called standard_form_builder.rb and place it in the helpers folder (at least that's what I've done)

```
class StandardFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def datepicker_field(method, html_options = {}
    text_field(:date_selector, :class => "datepicker") +
    hidden_field(method.to_sym, :id => "real_date")
  end
end

# view file
f.date_picker_field :date
```